# NavigationDrawer does nothing at itemclick

Tags: android, navigation, onclick, menuitem, navigation-drawer

I searched for hours if anybody had or has the same problem like me and I couldn't find anything that helped soliving this problem...

The Problem is, the NotificationDrawer opens up, with all items I gave him but he doesn't notice my onClick at any item! The APP just closes the Drawer and nothing happens, tried logging and different types of checking if any item is/was beeing clicked.

My used code:

```
    public class run extends Activity implements OnInitListener {

            private String[] drawerListViewItems;
            private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
            private ListView drawerListView;
            private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

            // nav drawer title
            private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

            // used to store app title
            private CharSequence mTitle;


         @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
                    // get list items from strings.xml
                    drawerListViewItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.options_array);
                    // 2. App Icon 
                    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                    // get ListView defined in activity_main.xml
                    drawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

                    // Set the adapter for the list view
                    drawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                            R.layout.drawer_list_item, drawerListViewItems));


                    // 2.1 create ActionBarDrawerToggle
                    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                            this,                  /* host Activity */
                            drawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                            R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
                            R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description */
                            R.string.drawer_close  /* "clos

    e drawer" description */
                        ){
                    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                        // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                        invalidateOptionsMenu();
                    }

                    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                        getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                        // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                        invalidateOptionsMenu();
                    }
                };

                // 2.2 Set actionBarDrawerToggle as the DrawerListener
                drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

                // 2.3 enable and show "up" arrow
                getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 

                // just styling option
                drawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

                drawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

                if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                    // on first time display view for first nav item
                    Log.d("LOGTAG", "DoSomething");
                }
    /**
         * Slide menu item click listener
         * */
        private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                // display view for selected nav drawer item
                selectItem(position);
            }
        }

private void selectItem(int position) {
        Log.d("LOGTAG", "ETWAS WURDE GEÄHLT! " + position);
        switch(position) {
        case 0:
            Log.d("LOGTAG", "ITEM 0 GEWÄHLT!");
        case 1:
            Log.d("LOGTAG", "Hier ist jetzt DING 1 gewählt!");
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Item 1 Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //          mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Lauf beenden")
            .setMessage("Bist du sicher?")
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setPositiveButton("Ja",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                        int which) {
                    // Yes button clicked, do something
                    finish();
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Nein", null).show();
            //          return true;

        default:
            //          return (position);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        menu.getItem(0).setVisible(false);
        menu.getItem(1).setVisible(false);
        menu.getItem(3).setVisible(false);


        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.close:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
}
```

strings.xml

```
<!-- TestTest -->
    <string-array name="options_array">
        <item>End run</item>
        <item>Test X</item>
    </string-array>
    <string name="drawer_open">StringDrawerOpen</string>
    <string name="drawer_close">StringDrawerClose</string>
```

drawer_list_items.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"/>
```

activity_main.xml

> ```
> <FrameLayout
>     android:id="@+id/content_frame"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent" />
>
>
> <ListView
>     android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
>     android:layout_width="200dp"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:layout_gravity="start"
>     android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
>     android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
>     android:dividerHeight="0dp"
>     android:background="#111"/>
>
> <LinearLayout
>     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:background="#FFFFFF"
>     android:orientation="vertical" >
>
>     <RelativeLayout
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="480dp" >
>
>         <ImageView
>             android:id="@+id/herzschlagImg"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:contentDescription="@string/heartImgDes"
>             android:src="@drawable/heartbeat" />
>
>         <ImageView
>             android:id="@+id/distanzImg"
>             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:contentDescription="@string/distImgDes"
>             android:paddingTop="150dp"
>             android:src="@drawable/distance" />
>
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/geschwindigkeit"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/distanz"
>             android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/distanz"
>             android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/geschwindigkeitVar"
>             android:text="@string/speed"
>             android:textSize="40sp" />
>
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/herzschlag"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>             android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
>             android:minHeight="60dp"
>             android:minWidth="200dp"
>             android:text="@string/heartbeat"
>             android:textSize="40sp" />
>
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/herzschlagVar"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/herzschlag"
>             android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/herzschlag"
>             android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
>             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/distanzVar"
>             android:text="@string/heartbeatDes"
>             android:textSize="30sp" />
>
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/geschwindigkeitVar"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/distanz"
>             android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/distanz"
>             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>             android:text="@string/speedDes"
>             android:textSize="30sp" />
>
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/distanz"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/distanzImg"
>             android:layout_alignRight="@+id/start"
>             android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
>             android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
>             android:text="@string/distance"
>             android:textSize="40sp" />
>
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/feedback"
>             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>             android:layout_height="85dp"
>             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>             android:background="#848482"
>             android:gravity="center"
>             android:text="@string/feed"
>             android:textSize="30sp" />
>
>         <Button
>             android:id="@+id/start"
>             android:layout_width="100dp"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/stop"
>             android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/stop"
>             android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/herzschlag"
>             android:onClick="startTime"
>             android:text="@string/btn_start"
>             android:textSize="35sp" />
>
>         <Button
>             android:id="@+id/stop"
>             android:layout_width="100dp"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_above="@+id/feedback"
>             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>             android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
>             android:layout_marginRight="29dp"
>             android:onClick="stopTime"
>             android:text="@string/btn_stop"
>             android:textSize="35sp" />
>
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/distanzVar"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/distanz"
>             android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/distanz"
>             android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
>             android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/geschwindigkeit"
>             android:text="@string/distanceDes"
>             android:textSize="30sp" />
>
>         <ImageView
>             android:id="@+id/zeitImg"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
>             android:contentDescription="@string/chronoDes"
>             android:paddingTop="20dp"
>             android:src="@drawable/timer" />
>
>         <Chronometer
>             android:id="@+id/zeit"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/geschwindigkeit"
>             android:layout_below="@+id/geschwindigkeit"
>             android:paddingTop="25dp"
>             android:textSize="40sp" />
>     </RelativeLayout>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

Sorry if the formatting is bad.
I don't get an exception or something, the logging also isn't helping...
Hope I haven't forgot anything to post.

I really hope you guys can help me!

Comment: Is your `ListView` (left_drawer) nested in something?

Comment: @user2713030 it's in the activity_main.xml:

Comment: <ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>

Comment: Log.d("LOGTAG", "ETWAS WURDE GEÄHLT! " + position);

Did you reach this point??

Answer (score 0):

In this piece of code

```
/**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
    ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }
```

OnItemClickListener interface is defined only on AdapterView and not on ListView. According to that, your code should give errors even before running.

`ListView.OnItemClickListener` should not work. The correct one should be `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`